# Allow access to a folder using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm working on a client site that was built using Zen Cart, I'm just adding a Wordpress blog to it. So I've setup a new folder called 'blog' and was just hoping that I could add a new tab to the top menu and link to the folder where Wordpress is installed.

The problem is I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error.

Is there any way to overcome this using htaccess ?

I've been doing a bit of Googling but could not figure it out.

Regards,
Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Create an .htaccess in the directory with the code:

```
Satisfy Any,Deny
Allow from all
```

Comment: Try now. Add deny to the first line.

Comment: Just tried that, now I'm getting: Error occurred: 500 - internal server error